# JQuery select options on change not displaying value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I select an option in my website, it should alert the option's value, but in this situation, the value is not alerted.

However when I tried it in JSFiddle, it works.

I am using jQuery 3.4.1 with jQuery loading at `head` tag.

My javascript script file is located at the bottom of `body` tag

HTML code

```
<div class = 'custom-select'>
  <select id = 'choice'>
    <option value = ''></option>
    <option value = 'one' selected>One</option>
    <option value = 'two'>Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
$(function() {
    $('#choice').change(function() {
        alert($('#choice option:selected').text());
    });
});
```

Please advise me on what I am missing or doing wrong, thank you.

Comment: If it's working in your fiddle but not in your website try to check the console for any errors.

Comment: My console is not showing any error messages.

Comment: Can you try to add this `console.log("test")` right after `$(function() {`, and can you see this in your console?

Comment: Yes I can see the message in console.

Comment: james try `console.log($().jquery;)` this should tell you what version of jquery is loaded, simply to confirm that jquery has loaded correctly

Comment: Console message displays 3.4.1, which is the version of jQuery I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works.
1. Check your console for any errors.
2. Check if it is the first script that is included.
3. Check if javascript is enabled in your browser.

**Option 1 with jquery**:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#choice').change(function() {
        alert($('#choice option:selected').text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'custom-select'>
  <select id = 'choice'>
    <option value = ''></option>
    <option value = 'one' selected>One</option>
    <option value = 'two'>Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Option 2 without jquery:**

```js
function alert_dropdown(value){
   alert(value);     
}
```

```html
<div class = 'custom-select'>
      <select id = 'choice' onchange="alert_dropdown(this.value)">
        <option value = ''></option>
        <option value = 'one' selected>One</option>
        <option value = 'two'>Two</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I included the jQuery library on my `head` tag

Comment: I have added the `console.log($('#choice option:selected').text());` but there is still no message in the console whenever I change selection. But if I put the code outside of the `.change`, I get a console message of the value.

Comment: Is this all your code or do you use more libraries?

Comment: Did your browser disabled javascript? can you check that?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have Jquery included in the html. I added it and it worked. 
Try adding

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: If jquery was not loaded correctly it would return an error when he rand the code.

Answer (score 0):

In case your content is being added dynamically you could try the following. In addition use `val()` to get the select box option.

```
$(document).on('change', '#choice', (e) => {
   alert($(e.target).val());
});
```

If your content is not being added dynamically then simply use:

```
$('#choice').on('change', (e) => {
   alert($(e.target).val());
});
```

```js
$(document).on('change', '#choice', (e) => {
  alert($(e.target).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class='custom-select'>
  <select id='choice'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='one'>One</option>
    <option value='two'>Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```js
alert($("#choice > option:selected").val());
$("#choice").on("change", (e) => {
    alert(($(e.target).val().length ? $(e.target).val() : "Select Something!"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class='custom-select'>
  <select id='choice'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='one' selected>One</option>
    <option value='two'>Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```